# Is there any python lib could be used to analysis the local block data?

Tags: block, technical-analysis

Just downloaded all the block files to local and want to try some analysis on the transaction data in the block.
is there any python library can be used to do the analysis?

Comment: If I use rpc interface it will use more than 3 seconds for one command....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/keviny/bitcoin-block-parser
May could help for simple analysis